# Anki SRS software for Chrome OS

Tags: chrome-os, anki

[Anki](http://ankisrs.net) is an app for memorizing vocabulary or anything ([Spaced Repetition Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition#Software)).
It has apps for Linux, Mac, Windows, Android, iOS, and a sync protocol makes it easy to use it on several devices.

Is there an SRS app for [Chrome OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS) that can sync using the same sync protocol?

Preferably free & open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnkiDroid is [available on the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ankidroid-flashcards/ckmbkodkbmkmdjdimeiddeljndcneifo).

AnkiDroid is 100% compatible with Anki, even though it is developed by a different team.

Free and open source.

*Disclaimer: I maintain AnkiDroid*